# Java's Application Context in Django

Tags: java, python, django, servlets

For a Servlets based web application there exists something called an Application Context. It is an Object accessible from anywhere in the application and can be used to store data which is relevant in the context of the application.

Is there something like this in Django? If not, what are the alternates that are available in Django for use cases of an Application Context.

Comment: I guess [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) would be something similar - at least on a per-user basis. Globals need to be persisted manually (DB, redis, ...) - all in all, Django tends to be more shared-nothing-oriented than Servlets with their global app context.

Comment: hmm, Django does have Request and Session level context.

Comment: @miku you should add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be nothing like this in Django, there are thread locals which can be used, but they are not the exact same as Application context.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) would be something similar - at least on a per-user basis. Globals need to be persisted manually (DB, redis, ...) - all in all, Django tends to be more [shared-nothing-oriented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_nothing_architecture) than Servlets with their global app context.